# ADF lifecycle phases difference

Tags: oracle-adf

Difference between ADF initContext and prepareModel,since both preparing data by executing buisness service making it available through binding container which is a Map object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ADF initContext and prepareModel,since both preparing data by executing buisness service

This is not quite correct. The `initContext` sets up the BindingContext, which ensures the content of `DataBindings.cpx` is initialized and the binding container for the page to be prepared. The `prepareModel` is an execution point for data queries.

The other execution point, as [Timo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668722/59087) shows, is `PrepareRender`. Recommendation though is to keep the iterator default setting, which is "deferred" in which case only those iterators are refreshed and queried that have UI dependency.

Comment: Does it mean in prepareRender phase also buisness service gets executed i.e component gets refreshed for those component whose partialTrigger is set on other component.

Comment: actually the phase is prepare render : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b31974/adf_lifecycle.htm which is invoked before prepare render. In ADF you have two commonly used refresh hooks: prepare model and prepare render. The default setting is "deferred". Here the refresh is in render response for those bindings that are referenced from UI components. The refresh may not re-execute the query in the database but initially refresh the iterator held in ADF. If data needs to be queried though then this is when ithappens

Comment: Thanks Frank ,comments really helpful to understand ADF lifecycle.

Comment: @FrankNimphius When does the query get executed? Is it different than "Refresh"?

Answer (score 3):

The ADF model life cycle phases:

- **initContext** sets up the life cycle, working out what PageDefs to load.
- **prepareModel** creates the bindings object and adds it to the HTTP request. Parameters are also evaluated at this point.
- **applyInputValues** processes the values posted from the page and builds up an internal list of bindings to update and methods to    execute as required.
- **validateInputValues** applies the client-side validators to the list of updates presented by the applyInputValues phase. These validators are defined as nested f:validator and af:convertNumber components within an input component.
- **processUpdateModel** sends the validated changes to bound objects to the model layer.
- **validateModelUpdates** manages validation errors from the Model layer.
- **processComponentEvents** processes any listeners and action events queued up from the applyInputValues phase.
- **metadataCommit** manages part of the runtime customization capabilities of the framework.If the user has customized the page in some way such as moving components on the screen or adding in task flows via WebCenter, then those personalizations to the screen are saved away to the metadata repository (MDS) at this point.
- **prepareRender** is the last phase to execute before the page is displayed.

Note that in some situations (such as a modal dialog), the following code will not necessarily fire after the page has been rendered:

```
  public void afterPhase(PagePhaseEvent pagePhaseEvent) {
    if (pagePhaseEvent.getPhaseId() == Lifecycle.PREPARE_RENDER_ID) {
      injectRedirect();
    }
  }
```

This prevents the server code from being able to examine the af:document immediately after the document is rendered. For example the following will fail because there is no document available:

```
  return context.getViewRoot().getChildren().get(0).getClientId().equals("doc0");
```